# A question regarding the definition of an affine toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

I am reading about affine toric varieties from *Toric Varieties* by Cox, Little, and Shenck, and the definition of an affine toric variety is given as follows:

> An affine toric variety is an irreducible affine variety $V$ containing a torus $T_N \simeq (\mathbb{C}^\times)^n$ as a Zariski open subset such that the action of $T_N$ on itself extends to an algebraic action of $T_N$ on $V$.

This is first time I am reading this and I don't understand which action are they talking about. Are they saying any action between $T_N$ to $T_N$ will be extended to an algebraic action? It will be great if you can help me with this doubt.

Comment: I think "the action of $T_N$ on itself" means this. An element of $T_N$ is identified with $a\in (\mathbb{C}^{\times})^n$. This induces an action $\times a: (\mathbb{C}^{\times})^n\to (\mathbb{C}^{\times})^n, x\mapsto ax$ Under this idenitification, we get an action of $T_N$ on itself.

Comment: Ahh okay, are you sure about this? This might be the case I think

Comment: In group theory, this is often called the (left) regular action of $G$ on itself.

Comment: Or maybe its the natural group action that is the natural way a group G acts on itself, that is $\forall g,h \in G$ $g.h=g*h$, if $G=(G,*)$